# Passing two 2dimensional arrays to method one after the other, C#

Tags: c#, arrays, parameter-passing

I want to run my Sudoku checker (written in method *CheckSudokuSolution* on the bottom) with two sudoku solutions.
i'm not very experienced in passing parameters and although my research cannot do that:

I need to pass to method *CheckSudokuSolution* first my 1. Sudoku (in *Solution1*) and then the second (in *Solution2*).

Should I change something with the Solution1(), Solution2()?

If you have time for explainment, I would be happy. Thanks.

My program:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CheckSudokuSolution(s);
        
        CheckSudokuSolution(s);

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    static void Solution1()
    {
        int[,] s = new int[,]
        {
            { 4,3,5,2,6,9,7,8,1},
            { 6,8,2,5,7,1,4,9,3},
            { 1,9,7,8,3,4,5,6,2},
            { 8,2,6,1,9,5,3,4,7},
            { 3,7,4,6,8,2,9,1,5},
            { 9,5,1,7,4,3,6,2,8},
            { 5,1,9,3,2,6,8,7,4},
            { 2,4,8,9,5,7,1,3,6},
            { 7,6,3,4,1,8,2,5,9}
        };
        
    }
    static void Solution2()
    {
        int[,] s = new int[,]
        {
            { 1,5,2,4,8,9,3,7,6},
            { 7,3,9,2,5,6,8,4,1},
            { 4,6,8,3,7,1,2,9,5},
            { 3,8,7,1,2,4,6,5,9},
            { 5,9,1,7,6,3,4,2,8},
            { 2,4,6,8,9,5,7,1,3},
            { 9,1,4,6,3,7,5,8,7},
            { 6,2,5,9,4,8,1,3,7},
            { 8,7,3,5,1,2,9,6,4}
        };
        
    }

    static void CheckSudokuSolution(int[,] s )
    {
           // code 
    }
```

Comment: You need to make `Solution1` and `Solution2` `return` the array they create, so you can pass it to `CheckSudokuSolution`

Answer (score 2):

In `Main()`, you have no variable named `s`, so you get an error with what you currently have. I suggest making `Solution1` a static variable instead of a function:

```
    static int[,] Solution1 = new int[,]
        {
            { 4,3,5,2,6,9,7,8,1},
            { 6,8,2,5,7,1,4,9,3},
            { 1,9,7,8,3,4,5,6,2},
            { 8,2,6,1,9,5,3,4,7},
            { 3,7,4,6,8,2,9,1,5},
            { 9,5,1,7,4,3,6,2,8},
            { 5,1,9,3,2,6,8,7,4},
            { 2,4,8,9,5,7,1,3,6},
            { 7,6,3,4,1,8,2,5,9}
        };
```

Now you can pass it in directly:

```
        CheckSudokuSolution(Solution1);
```

Similarly for `Solution2`.

Comment: For me is important, that both arrays has the same name, because I want work with then further, your answer don't follow this principle.

Comment: At this level, they can have different names and you can still work with them in `CheckSudokuSolution()` as you want. I suggest you read more about variable scope and parameter passing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to get the all point there but you can use class in first place to see your arrays from the main then :

- Send your arrays to CheckSudokuSolution().
- Check the return value.

Exemple :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] s1 = CheckSudokuSolution(Solutions.s1);

        int[,] s2 = CheckSudokuSolution(Solutions.s2);


        // display sudoku s1

        int i = 0;
        foreach (var item in s1)
        {
            if (i == 9)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                i = 0;
            }
            Console.Write(item.ToString());
            i++;
        }
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    public static class Solutions
    {
        public static int[,] s1 = new int[,]
        {
        { 4,3,5,2,6,9,7,8,1},
        { 6,8,2,5,7,1,4,9,3},
        { 1,9,7,8,3,4,5,6,2},
        { 8,2,6,1,9,5,3,4,7},
        { 3,7,4,6,8,2,9,1,5},
        { 9,5,1,7,4,3,6,2,8},
        { 5,1,9,3,2,6,8,7,4},
        { 2,4,8,9,5,7,1,3,6},
        { 7,6,3,4,1,8,2,5,9}
        };

        public static int[,] s2 = new int[,]
        {
        { 1,5,2,4,8,9,3,7,6},
        { 7,3,9,2,5,6,8,4,1},
        { 4,6,8,3,7,1,2,9,5},
        { 3,8,7,1,2,4,6,5,9},
        { 5,9,1,7,6,3,4,2,8},
        { 2,4,6,8,9,5,7,1,3},
        { 9,1,4,6,3,7,5,8,7},
        { 6,2,5,9,4,8,1,3,7},
        { 8,7,3,5,1,2,9,6,4}
        };
    }
    static int[,] CheckSudokuSolution(int[,] s)
    {
        // Do something with s
        return s;
    }
}
```